# Pass anonymous enum as function argument

Tags: c++11, enums

Is it possible to pass anonymous enum as a function parameter? Something like that:

```
class Foo
{
    enum
    {
        One,
        Two,
        Three
    };
};

void Function( /* ??? */ e)
{
    switch (e)
    {
        case Foo::One: // do stuff...
        case Foo::Two: // ...
    }
}
```

Solution attempt:

I was trying to determine what's the type of Foo::One by using auto and checking deduced type:

```
auto u = Foo::One;
```

But it turned out to be `Foo<anonymous enum>` so I can't really use that in code.

Comment: is the enum from 3rd-party source so you can't modify it? otherwise a proper solution would be just to give it a name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could turn the function into a function template like this:

```
template <class Enum> void Function(Enum e)
{
    switch (e)
    {
        case Foo::One: // do stuff...
        case Foo::Two: // ...
    }
}
```

It can be instantiated and called via

```
Function(Foo::One);
```

Comment: Nice. I always use template when I am not sure what type something is. However this is not always appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

I found a possible solution. Ugly, but works:

```
void Function(decltype(Foo::One) e) {}
```